# Simple curiosity about performance using OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I develop a small 3D engine using OpenGL and GLSL.

Here's a part of the rendering code :

```
void video::RenderBatch::Render(void)
{
    type::EffectPtr pShaderEffect = EffectManager::GetSingleton()
        .FindEffectByName(this->m_pMaterial->GetAssocEffectName());

    pShaderEffect->Bind();
    {
        ///VERTEX ATTRIBUTES LOCATIONS.
        {
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_POSITION, "VertexPosition");
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_TEXTURE, "VertexTexture");
            pShaderEffect->BindAttribLocation(scene::VERTEX_NORMAL, "VertexNormal");
        }
        //SEND MATRIX UNIFORMS.
        {
            glm::mat3 normalMatrix = glm::mat3(glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[0]),
                glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[1]), glm::vec3(this->m_ModelViewMatrix[2]));

            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("ModelViewProjMatrix", this->m_ModelViewProjMatrix);
            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("ModelViewMatrix", this->m_ModelViewMatrix);
            pShaderEffect->SetUniform("NormalMatrix", normalMatrix);
        }
        this->SendLightUniforms(pShaderEffect); //LIGHT MATERIALS TO BE SENT JUST ONCE */

        pShaderEffect->SendMaterialUniforms( //SEND MATERIALS IF CHANGED
            this->m_pMaterial->GetName());

        this->m_pVertexArray->Lock();
        {
            this->m_pIndexBuffer->Lock();
            {
                RenderData renderData = this->GetVisibleGeometryData();
                {
                    glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei*)&renderData.count[0], GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                        (const GLvoid **)&renderData.indices[0], renderData.count.size());
                }
            }
            this->m_pIndexBuffer->Unlock();
        }
        this->m_pVertexArray->Unlock();
    }
    pShaderEffect->Release();
}
```

I noticed the call of the function 'SetUniform' creates a great loss of FPS (more than 1000 FPS without it to +- 65 FPS with it!). Just ONE simple call of this function suffice!

Here's the code of the function 'this->SetUniform' (for matrix 4x4):

```
void video::IEffectBase::SetUniform(char const *pName, glm::mat4 mat)
{
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(this->m_Handle, pName);
    if (location >= 0)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mat));
}
```

In reality just the call of the function 'glGetUniformLocation' or the function 'glUniformMatrix4fv' suffice to have a such loss of FPS. Is it normal to go over 1000 FPS to 65 FPS with a unique call of this function ? However buffer binding or shader program binding don't have a such effect! (if I comment all the 'SetUniform' calls I still have more than 1000 FPS even with all the bindings (state changes)!).

So, to sum up the situation, all the functions I need to send uniform informations to the shader program (matrix and material data and so on...) seem to have a huge impact to the frame rate. However in this example my scene is only composed of a unique cube mesh! Nothing terrible to render for the GPU!

But I don't think the problem comes from the GPU because the impact of my program on it is just laughable (according to 'GPUShark'):

[image]

Only 6%! But just the display of the window (without the geometry) suffices to reach 6%! So the rendering of my cube have almost none impact on the GPU. So I think the problem comes from the CPU/GPU data transfer... I think it's normal to have a loss of performance using these function but go from more than 1000 FPS to 65 FPS it's incredible! And just to draw a simple geometry!

Is there a way to have better performance or is it normal to have a such loss of FPS using this technique of sending data?

What do you think about that ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `glGetUniformLocation` every time you need to set a uniform's value.  Uniform locations don't change for a given shader (unless you recompile it), so look up the uniforms *once* after compiling the shader and save the location values for use in your `Render` function.

Comment: Oh, ok effectively I will save it once after compilation. It was just because of the function 'glGetUniformLocation' calls. The functions glUniformXXX have a very very little impact (I still have more than 1000 FPS using them). Thanks very much for your help! Bye.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `BindAtttribLocation()` calls. They won't have any effect here. `glBindAttribLocation()` needs to be called *before linking* the shader program to have any effect.